# Temporal filter on a pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, filtering

I have a pd.DataFrame 'join3' with multiple columns like this:

```
    start   end      regstart  regend
A   01:00   03:00    02:00     02:30
B   07:00   08:00    07:30     09:00
C   12:00   13:00    15:00     17:00
```

now I want to filter and get only those rows, where the Interval start-end intersects with the interval regstart-regend. In the example above, item C would be filtered out.

I do this:

```
join4 = join3[ ((join3['regend'] > join3['start']) and (join3['regend'] < join3['end']) ) or 
               ((join3['regstart'] > join3['start']) and (join3['regstart'] < join3['end']))  ]
```

But I get the error "ValueError: the truth value of a Series ins ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item() a.any() or a.all().

What is the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `or` to `|` and `and` to `&` for bitwise `and` and `or`.

```
join4 = join3[ ((join3['regend'] > join3['start']) &
                (join3['regend'] < join3['end']) ) |
               ((join3['regstart'] > join3['start']) &
                (join3['regstart'] < join3['end']))  ]
```